# [mongodb], How can I get maximum value of a document with many different fields through aggregation? sub field names are same

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have following document:
[image]

Below layouts.nodes, there are many node fields(no limit), and I want to find the maximum x value in these nodes. How can I achieve this? (this specific document format is a configuration of a frontend library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `$objectToArray` to set an array of values and `$max` to find the item with the maximum value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {_id: 0, data: {$objectToArray: "$layouts.nodes"}}},
  {$project: {maxX: {$max: "$data.v.x"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XqnsgfOyi03)

Comment: Thanks. Can I use $max directly other than $recude? And is there a go example? I found it difficult to transform it to go code.

Comment: Well, yes. You can use `$max`. Good catch! I updated the answer accordingly. I don't have a GO example

Comment: is "$$REMOVE" used to remove data field from the result?

Comment: Yes. We just wanted it temporarily

Comment: how can I remove other unnecessary fields also, I only need the max value.

Comment: Use `$project` for it. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Can we remove other unnecessary fields first and then do the following things? That only keeps layouts.nodes. I think it may be faster.

Comment: Sure. look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zat8FrFwBPV)

Answer (score 0):

The go stage code example:

```golang
    matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"_id", "1"}}}}
    projectStage := bson.D{{"$project", bson.D{{"_id", 0}, {"nodes", "$layouts.nodes"}}}}
    transformStage := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{{"data", bson.D{{"$objectToArray", "$nodes"}}}}},
    }
    calcStage := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{{"maxX", bson.D{{"$max", "$data.v.x"}}}}},
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).